# Is it possible to join multiple objects without losing their own UV spaces?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I am working on a 3D character for export out of blender, but I need to keep the UVs of every object separate. I need to have one object with multiple UVs for different part of the mesh. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your UV maps have unique names(before joining), they will be kept separate when joined into one mesh. You can change the names of UV maps in the Object Data tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

[UV Maps Panel](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_management.html#uv-maps-panel)

[Multiple UV Maps](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_management.html#multiple-uv-maps)

Comment: Uv maps name? before join? I should go to the display of data , above of Vertex group there is a slot with UV map? be more specific please.

Comment: Edited answer with additional info.

Comment: so first of all I should unwrap the mesh in the respective UV map? asign a name before join? and use a general UVmap for join and one dedicated uv map for the mesh , the part with it owns uv.

Comment: From your question it seemed as if you already had multiple unwrapped objects and you wanted to join them while keeping their UVs. If its just one object and you want multiple UVs, you just add UVs in the UV Map panel, and name just for organization purposes.

Comment: it is soldier model, I need to export the whole model , but I need vertex color material for an ID map to use in substance painter while I am painting every part of the body with the respective material .